# MusicPlayerSetPlayRateScalar causes hang/freeze in __psynch_mutexwait

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm using `AVFoundation`'s `MusicPlayer` to play MIDI music in a game, and I periodically call `MusicPlayerSetPlayRateScalar` to set the tempo. I recently ported the game from Objective-C to Swift, and since then I've been getting hanging/freezing after a couple dozen calls to this function. When the freeze happens and I pause execution, my main thread is always sitting in the following state:

`` * thread #1: libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 8
    frame #1: libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_mutex_lock_wait + 96
    frame #2: AudioToolbox`CAMutex::Lock() + 52
    frame #3: AudioToolbox`SequencePlayer::SetTempoScaleFactor(double) + 36
    frame #4: AudioToolbox`MusicPlayerSetPlayRateScalar + 136 ``

CPU usage jumps to 100% when this happens, and memory usage starts growing steadily. I don't have any other threads of my own running. The other thread activity varies, but here's an example (top level of the other threads' stack traces):

`` thread #5: libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent_qos + 8, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager'
  thread #6: libsystem_kernel.dylib`__semwait_signal + 8, name = 'gputools.smt_poll.0x126fe8680'
  thread #10: libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient'
  thread #11: libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 8, name = 'AudioStreamerImpl::sIOWorkerProcess'
  thread #12: libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_decrement_exception_refcount + 32, name = 'AURemoteIO::IOThread'
  thread #13: libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'AURemoteIO::IOThread' ``

I'd have guessed some kind of deadlock given the mutexes and semaphores, but the CPU and memory usage patterns seem to indicate otherwise. How can I debug this further?

(Incidentally, the debugger sometimes crashes when I do `bt all` in this situation, but I doubt that's related.)

Comment: I'm going to guess there's some kind of C++ voodoo going on the background that makes it impossible to do this with Swift. Is there any chance you can use the new AVAudioSequencer instead?

Comment: @matt Woah, I hadn't heard about `AVAudioSequencer` (unsurprising, since there's no API documentation for it yet). I just rewrote my music player using it (with about 1/4 as much code), and the freezing is gone. Awesome!

Comment: Glad to here it! I've given my comment as an answer so we can close this one out. Delighted that this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that the Apple folks said in the WWDC 2015 Core Audio video makes me think that there's a lot of C++ voodoo going on behind the scenes in areas like this, and that Swift therefore can't interface with it unless you take certain precautions (and I didn't understand what they are). In this situation, if you don't need backwards compatibility too far back, you might want to try using the new AVAudioSequencer instead. I've found it very easy and reliable.